# I can't drag and drop any button or object to my user interface in Xcode10

Tags: xcode10

I can't drag and drop any button or object to my user interface in Xcode10, because it just shows either the message "no selection" or "not applicable".

I will add some screenshots of this, and I hope you can help me.
Deleting derivedData and opening another view or view controller didn't work out.

I'm currently using an MacBook Air 2017 edition.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/68BPN.png // no selection
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFpSV.png // not applicable

Answer (score 0):

On XCode 10, there is a new spot for UIKit elements on storyboard, and you can see where it's available in this image:
[image: UIKit]